# How can I resolve this pdf-generator problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, pdf-generation

I'm new at field.
I trying to make pdf generator web application with express.js using html-pdf package.
I have condition on `engagement` variable

```
module.exports =
({rs,periode,engagement,siren,num,rue,codePostal,ville,contratRef,commentaire,nomPrenom,fonction,phone,mail}) => {
const today = new Date();
return `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>



    window.onload = function test() {


      var o = (document.getElementById('choix1'));
      var u = (document.getElementById('choix2'));


      if (${ engagement } == "oui") {
        o.checked = true;
      }else if (${ engagement } == "non") {
        u.checked = true
      }
    }


  </script>
```

When client send data to back end the app crashed and error "cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" in my terminal. how can I resolve this problem ?

Server API code:

```
app.post('/pdf', (req, res) => {
  pdf.create(pdfDocument(req.body), {}).toFile('result.pdf', (err) => {
    if(err) { res.send(Promise.reject()); }
    res.send(Promise.resolve());
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like issue in server side code. Can you share request handler code for the API being called?

Comment: app.post('/pdf', (req, res) => {
    pdf.create(pdfDocument(req.body), {}).toFile('result.pdf', (err) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send(Promise.reject());
        }

        res.send(Promise.resolve());
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

We normally get `cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` if response is returned twice or if headers are set after response is returned. You can read more about it in following stack overflow post:

[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

If response object is not being updated from any other middleware apart from request handler code shared, there are chances that `pdf.create` returned error and `res.send` got called twice -

1. within if block for error and
2. res.send statement after if

If you add return before `res.send` like below, issue should be resolved

```
app.post('/pdf', (req, res) => {
  pdf.create(pdfDocument(req.body), {}).toFile('result.pdf', (err) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.send(`Error in generating PDF`);
    }
    return res.send(`PDF created successfully!`);
  });
});
```

Also, I am not sure why you are returning Promise.resolve() / Promise.reject() in response.

Comment: (node:10004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:10004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: That is because you are returning `Promise.reject()` in response. I am not sure why you are doing that (mentioned same thing in last line of answer as well). You will have to return proper response for this to be fixed.

Comment: i'm not sure why i did that because i follow someone in tutorial video to do this web application
i'm new at this field like i said from the begin

Comment: For now, I will update answer to return string in response so that exception is gone. You will have to update it as per API requirements.

Comment: the app doesn't crash and also doesn't work.the variable do not arrive to backend

Comment: I can only help till here, you will have to debug it further to figure out the issue. Maybe start by adding console logs in `if(err)` block.